# odd php output for the Hello World PHP script

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm walking myself through a php tutorial. I created a new Fedora 33 VM and installed httpd and php and php-common

I performed these steps:

1. started apache with:  systemctl start httpd
2. created a file in /var/www/html called hello.php (as root)
3. chmod apache:apache /var/www/html/hello.php
4. edited the /var/www/html/hello.php file and added this:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

5. pointed a web browser at the VM `http://10.16.0.107/hello.php`

It sort of works, but my output looks like this:

```
Hello World

'; ?>
```

Note the extra line with the question mark and greater than sign...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very odd, even happens when you run the code snippet. But it does not happen on my server

Comment: Is PHP installed on your server?  Your code runs fine: https://ideone.com/wYJbNL

Comment: php is installed:

# rpm -qa | grep php


php-common-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-cli-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-json-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-opcache-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-pdo-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-xml-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-fpm-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-sodium-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-mbstring-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
php-7.4.13-1.fc33.x86_64
vim-syntastic-php-3.10.0-7.fc33.noarch

Comment: Solved:

I uncommented this in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

    #
    # Uncomment the following lines to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
    # files as PHP source code:
    #
    <FilesMatch \.phps$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>

Comment: PHP might be installed on your system, but somehow Apache isn't using it and the browser is just seeing what it thinks is HTML with some tags it doesn't understand. Try reinstalling Apache then PHP in that order.